# ¿Por qué me aparece este error en Delphi?

Tags: delphi, compilar

Estoy tratando de instalar SynEdit en Delphi pero me aparece el siguiente error a la hora de tratar de compilarlo:

```
E2225 Never-build package 'designide' must be recompiled
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: No comentas qué versión de delphi estás utilizando, cosa importante. or otro lado, la mayoría de veces que he visto este error, es porque se estaba utilizando una versión de componentes diferente a la del IDE. Revisa que la versión de SynEdit que estás instalando sea la correcta.

Comment: La versión que tengo de Delphi es la 10.4 Community Edition.

Comment: ¿Y de dónde estás obteniendo los componentes SynEdit?
¿Has probado a realizar la instalación a través de GetIt!? En esa versión ya está disponible.

Comment: En la página GetIt solo me aparece la opción de ver licencia, pero no veo la manera de descargarlo.

Comment: Me refería a GetIt! desde el IDE. Menú de Tools. Si no aparece esa opción es porque es una versión community.
En ese caso, pon la URL desde donde lo has descargado y cómo lo estás instalando/compilando.